# In Adobe Fireworks, how do I make the margin beneath the text in a text box smaller?

Tags: text, adobe-fireworks

I'm trying to either make the inner margin in a text box smaller, or align the text on the bottom of the text box in fireworks. (by text box, I mean the box surrounding a text element).

With the extra space beneath the text, I can't place the text box close enough to the element beneath it without the two boxes overlapping. Not sure I'm making this clear; please see the screenshot.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: What screenshot? And have you tried just reducing the bottom margin of the paragraph? You should be able to set it to a negative number if needed.

Comment: not enough 'reputation points' to add the screenshot

Comment: i tried your suggestion and couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

what you mean is to align the text to the handles surrounding it, I am afraid you cannot do that!

However you have a couple of options:

- You can use your keyboard's arrow keys to move the text to the exact position you desire
- You create a rectangle behind your text and use the align tools to position your text relative to that rectangle (you can delete the rectangle afterwords) To do this,

  1 Select both the rectangle and text together (holding down the SHIFT key).

  2 Go to Window -> Align

  3 Select "Relative to Object"

  4 Use one of the options for alignment
- You use "Attach to Path" option:

  1 Draw a straight line using the pen tool

  2 Select both the line and your text using the SHIFT key

  3 Go to Text -> Attach to Path.

Hope this helps